# Iterating through one variable in a vector of struct with lower/upper bound

Tags: c++, sorting, optimization, vector, struct

I have 2 structs, one simply has 2 values:

```
struct combo { 
int output;
int input;
};
```

And another that sorts the input element based on the index of the output element:

```
struct organize { 
bool operator()(combo const &a, combo const &b) 
  { 
    return a.input < b.input;
  }
};
```

Using this:

```
sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), organize());
```

What I'm trying to do with this, is iterate through the input varlable, and check if each element is equal to another input 'in'.

If it is equal, I want to insert the value at the same index it was found to be equal at for input, but from output into another temp vector.

I originally went with a more simple solution (when I wasn't using a structs and simply had 2 vectors, one input and one output) and had this in a function called copy:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i){

   if(input == in){

       temp.push_back(output[i]);

   } 
}
```

Now this code did work exactly how I needed it, the only issue is it is simply too slow. It can handle 10 integer inputs, or 100 inputs but around 1000 it begins to slow down taking an extra 5 seconds or so, then at 10,000 it takes minutes, and you can forget about 100,000 or 1,000,000+ inputs.

So, I asked how to speed it up on here (just the function iterator) and somebody suggested sorting the input vector which I did, implemented their suggestion of using upper/lower bound, changing my iterator to this:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = input.begin(); 
auto lowerIt = std::lower_bound(input.begin(), input.end(), in);
auto upperIt = std::upper_bound(input.begin(), input.end(), in);

 for (auto it = lowerIt; it != upperIt; ++it)
 {
     temp.push_back(output[it - input.begin()]);
 }
```

And it worked, it made it much faster, I still would like it to be able to handle 1,000,000+ inputs in seconds but I'm not sure how to do that yet.

I then realized that I can't have the input vector sorted, what if the inputs are something like:

```
input.push_back(10);
input.push_back(-1);

output.push_back(1);
output.push_back(2);
```

Well then we have 10 in input corresponding to 1 in output, and -1 corresponding to 2. Obviously 10 doesn't come before -1 so sorting it smallest to largest doesn't really work here.

So I found a way to sort the input based on the output. So no matter how you organize input, the indexes match each other based on what order they were added.

My issue is, I have no clue how to iterate through just input with the same upper/lower bound iterator above. I can't seem to call upon just the input variable of myVector, I've tried something like:

```
std::vector<combo>::iterator it = myVector.input.begin();
```

But I get an error saying there is no member 'input'.

How can I iterate through just input so I can apply the upper/lower bound iterator to this new way with the structs?

Also I explained everything so everyone could get the best idea of what I have and what I'm trying to do, also maybe somebody could point me in a completely different direction that is fast enough to handle those millions of inputs. Keep in mind I'd prefer to stick with vectors because not doing so would involve me changing 2 other files to work with things that aren't vectors or lists.

Thank you!

Comment: So, fundementally.   Are you just trying to decide if there are any duplicate values for the input variable in your struct?   Or do you need to know where the duplicates are?

Comment: @EvilTeach Essentially, I need determine if  'in' is equal to any element inside of input, and for each element inside input that does equal 'in', I want to take the index of each match, and add the value at the same index from output, inserting each of those values into a temp vector.

Comment: @EvilTeach I realize my explanation is poor, so if in input, I have the elements: 1, 5, 5, 8, 9 and in output I have the elements 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 'in' is equal to lets say 5. I would search input, find that 5 is at index 1, and 2. Then I need to copy the same value at index 1 and 2 of output (in this case that would be 2 and 3) to a vector called temp.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you sort it in smallest to largest (x is an integer after all)  that you should be able to use [std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) to find duplicates in the array, and process them properly.   For the performance issues, you might consider using [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) to preallocate space for your large vector, so that your push back operations don't have to reallocate memory as often.